# First Table pagination Conflicts with Second Table Pagination -codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have A strange issue..I am populating pagination for two tables in a single view from same controller function. Using two different Config settings..say config1[] and config2[]. Say my second table's per_page is 5..Now when I click on the 5th page of the first table, my second table's $config2['cur_tag_open'] gets highlighted. Note that my second tables data is not changing..But it shows like it have moved from 1st page to 2nd page in Second Table. I tried with many things but could not figure out what is going wrong. Thanks in advance

Please see the configuration..

```
 A) $config1['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "my_application/dashboard";
    $config1['per_page'] = 10;
    $config1['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config1['num_links'] = 5;
    $config1['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
    $config1['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config1['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="side">';
    $config1['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config1['first_link'] = '<<';
    $config1['last_link'] = '>>';
    $config1["total_rows"] = 0;

    $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
      $this->pagination->initialize($config1);

B) $config2['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "my_application/dashboard/0";
    $config2['per_page'] = 14;
    $config2['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config2['num_links'] = 5;

    $config2['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';

    $config2['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config2['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="side">';
    $config2['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config2['first_link'] = '<<';
    $config2['last_link'] = '>>';
    $config2["total_rows"] = 0;
    $offset1 = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config2);
Now when ever I go to 14 th page of 1st table, Second table's  2nd tab gets highlighted as if it is selected..but data does not change..
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config/routes.php
Define a separate route for each pagination. Then Check

```
 $config1['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "routeUrl-1";
    $config1['per_page'] = 10;
    $config1['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config1['num_links'] = 5;
    $config1['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
    $config1['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config1['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="side">';
    $config1['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config1['first_link'] = '<<';
    $config1['last_link'] = '>>';
    $config1["total_rows"] = 0;

    $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
      $this->pagination->initialize($config1);

B) $config2['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "routeUrl-2";
    $config2['per_page'] = 14;
    $config2['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config2['num_links'] = 5;

    $config2['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';

    $config2['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config2['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="side">';
    $config2['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config2['first_link'] = '<<';
    $config2['last_link'] = '>>';
    $config2["total_rows"] = 0;
    $offset1 = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config2);
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me how to do it in config/routes.php.

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter 2x or 3x?

Comment: Codeigniter 2x.

Comment: use like this 

$route['pagination1/(:num)'] = 'controllerName/functionName/$1';
$route['pagination2/(:num)'] = 'controllerName/functionName/$1';

Comment: $route['pagination1'] = 'controller/dashboard';
$route['pagination2'] = 'controller/dashboard/0';

  $config2['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "pagination1";

Comment: $config2['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "pagination2";
but Error page is showing....

Comment: $route['pagination1/(:num)'] = 'controller/dashboard/$1';
$route['pagination2/(:num)'] = 'controller/dashboard/0/$1'; 

  $config1['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "pagination1";

   $config2['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "pagination2";

Now when I click, it shows http://localhost/myapplication/pagination1/40..but pagination is not working...same time the second table tab is not highlighted..it is solved..but pagination is not working..